# Excel: Subtracting Dates Without Reference Cells

Tags: excel, formulas, days

I want to program a cell to calculate the number of days I have left before I meet a deadline.

I would like to do this without reference cells, unlike [this tutorial.](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/qt/090728-subtract-dates-day-function.htm)

An (incorrectly formatted) example of the kind of formula I want would be:`=(3/2/2015-TODAY())`, where 3/2/2015 is my deadline. This yields some negative serial number,`-42051.00`, which yields a `#NUM!` error when put into the `DAY` formula.

Any idea how to do this without putting `TODAY()` and `3/2/2015` into their own reference cells? I would like to use functions to keep these paraments completely embedded in the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Right clock the cell with the answer and reformat it as NUMBER. You want to use the Days function not the date function.

=DATE(2015,3,2)-TODAY() is what you want, but I would recommend doing the date in a separate cell for a number of reasons and using "today()" in the formula.

EDIT: Anyone trying to find midpoints would use the date function in this case.

Also, as a general rule for people trying to subtract dates the two trouble shooting methods you want are

A) Check your format-If you want number of dates, it needs to be set as number, if you want a date, you need it to set as date. If you get a long decimal it means you have it formatted as general OR your expression returns a date value rather than a number value. Refer to my original answer.

B) Reverse your dates. Depending on the function and what you want, you may need to move the dates around.

Answer (score 0):

`=DATEDIF(DATEVALUE("03/02/2015"), TODAY(), "d")`